# vert.x: Register failureHandler to all routes

Tags: groovy, vert.x

In my app I have routes like:

```
router.get "/api/$name/:id" handler this.&details
router.post "/api/$name" consumes JSON produces JSON handler this.&save
router.delete "/api/$name/:id" handler this.&delete
// a lot more of those
```

I want to register a `failureHandler` to all of those routes, to do simple error logging like:

```
void handleError( RoutingContext rc ) {
    Throwable failure = rc.failure()
    log.error failure.message, failure
    rc.response().setStatusCode 500 putHeader 'content-type', JSON end """{ "message":"$failure.message"}"""
}
```

The doc shows, that I can register the `failureHandler` on per-route basis like so:

```
router.get "/api/$name/:id" handler this.&details failureHander this.&handleError
```

which would become pretty verbose and self-repeating very soon.

I tried to register a handler on a wildcard path:

```
router.route '/*' failureHandler this.&handleError
```

but that is ignored.

Is there a way to register a global `failureHandler`?

Comment: What you probably want is `router.route` instead of `router.get` so that the handler is registered for every HTTP method.

Comment: yeah, tried that as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out to be fairly straight-forward. I was misguided by the FailureHandler registered in one of the super-classes.

The final code looks like this:

```
router.route().with{
  handler BodyHandler.create() 
  handler ResponseContentTypeHandler.create()
  handler FaviconHandler.create( 'webroot/favicon.ico' )

  failureHandler{ rc -> 
    log.error 'Error occured', rc.failure()
    rc.next()
  }
  failureHandler ErrorHandler.create( WebEnvironment.development() )
}
```

Herewith I define a chain of failure-handlers, the 1st of which logs the exception off, and delegates to the Vert.x' handler to render a nice response.

Hope it can help someone to save days of reverse-engineering :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm certain there are better ways (would love to hear them!) and the following may look verbose, but for my particular use case I ended up chaining [`Router.errorHandler`](https://vertx.io/docs/apidocs/io/vertx/ext/web/Router.html#errorHandler-int-io.vertx.core.Handler-) handlers to handle errors by status code. This handles errors from any/all routes (e.g., `ctx.fail(400)`, `ctx.fail(404)`, etc.) as well as situations when Vert.x itself throws an error, e.g., `500`:

```java
var router = Router.router(vertx);


// ...all your other routes...


router
    .errorHandler(400, MainErrorHandler::handle)
    .errorHandler(404, MainErrorHandler::handle)
    .errorHandler(500, MainErrorHandler::handle) /* etc. */ ;
```

```java
class MainErrorHandler {

    public static void handle(RoutingContext ctx) {
        var statusCode = ctx.statusCode();
        var responseBody = "";

        switch (statusCode) {
            case 400:
                responseBody = "your customized 400 response...";
                break;
            case 404:
                responseBody = "your customized 404 response...";
                break;
            default:
                // 500
                responseBody = "your customized 500 response...";
        }

        ctx.response().setStatusCode(statusCode).end(responseBody);
    }
}
```